# Error of: Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Application' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm running this in Visual Studio 2013.

For `Application.Current.Shutdown` I get:

`'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Application' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'`.

I tried using `using SystemInformation = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation;` in place of `using System.Windows.Forms` as one site suggested but I get the error:

`The type or namespace name 'OpenFileDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` for the line `OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();`

How can I fix it so I can use OpenFileDialog? I want an open file dialog box to appear.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using PTDGUI.View;  

private void mnuExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       string fileName;
       fileName = dlg.FileName;
       MessageBox.Show(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a winforms application or a console appilcation ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but it's a wpf if that helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to avoid ambiguity of Application class.

```
private void mnuExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

**Update**

The reason for this ambiguity is both namespace `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Windows` contains definition for class `Application`. so at this point c# compiler gets confused which implementation of Application to refer to.

If you are not referring any classes from `System.Windows.Forms` you can remove it from the list of using.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I read somewhere else that's how you do it but it wasn't descriptive enough as you put it. And I had to do the same thing with `MessageBox.show` by saying `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show`

Comment: @Question_Guy Update my answer for the cause of that error.

Comment: I am using `System.Windows.Forms`, hence `OpenFileDialog`

Comment: @Question_Guy ok then you need to apply fully qualified name of Application class with namespace as my illustrated on code snippet in answer.